# Using recursive folder delete and folder delete causes stack overflow

Tags: php, recursion, command-line-interface

I'm using PHP's CLI for creating a program. There's a folder named `/compile` which holds all of the compiled files after it's CLI call, this folder gets the constant `__COMPILE__`. I'm using this function and using the constant to use as the location: (Location: **C:\Users\Jeklin\Documents\GitHub\spitfire-engine\compiled**):

> **Fatal error:** Allowed memory size of **134217728** bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in **C:\Users\Jeklin\Documents\GitHub\spitfire-engine\sys\compiler\Launcher.compiler.php** on line **66**

This is the function I'm using:

```
/*59*/    public function p_sweep_compile_dir()
/*60*/      { $dir = __COMPILE__;
/*61*/        if (is_dir($dir)) {
/*62*/          $objects = scandir($dir);
/*63*/          foreach ($objects as $object) {
/*64*/            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
/*65*/              if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir")
/*66*/                 $this->p_sweep_compile_dir($dir."/".$object);
/*67*/              else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
/*68*/            }
/*69*/          }
/*70*/          reset($objects);
/*71*/          rmdir($dir);
/*72*/        } else die('tried to delete a non-folder from p_sweep_compile_dir');
/*73*/      }
```

I can see that on line 66 that includes the recursion method to try to get deeper into the file structure, although the structure is very shallow, this is the `__COMPILE__` directories setup:

```
|--compiled
     |---app
     |---public
     |---sys
     |index.html
```

Comment: `public function p_sweep_compile_dir(no_args!?) {...` each time you call the function, you reset dir to `__COMPILE__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure who wrote that code but this would make more sense:

```
/*59*/    public function p_sweep_compile_dir($dir = null) // default $dir to null unless something is passed into it
/*60*/      { $dir = ($dir === null ? __COMPILE__ : $dir); // If $dir is null then use __COMPILE__ otherwise use the $dir value
/*61*/        if (is_dir($dir)) {
/*62*/          $objects = scandir($dir);
/*63*/          foreach ($objects as $object) {
/*64*/            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
/*65*/              if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir")
/*66*/                 $this->p_sweep_compile_dir($dir."/".$object); // recurse self and provide deeper dir
/*67*/              else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
/*68*/            }
/*69*/          }
/*70*/          reset($objects);
/*71*/          rmdir($dir);
/*72*/        } else die('tried to delete a non-folder from p_sweep_compile_dir');
/*73*/      }
```

I have not tested this but in theory it should work.

See line #s 59, 60, and 66 for comments.

---

Side-note:

Assuming you have full control of this source code, for the love of all that is good in this world, please use opening and closing curly braces, **ALWAYS**. Some poor programmer is going to curse you for hours when they work on this after you stop working on it.

---

How I would write it:

```
public function p_sweep_compile_dir($dir = null) // default $dir to null unless something is passed into it
{
    $dir = ($dir === null ? __COMPILE__ : $dir); // If $dir is null then use __COMPILE__ otherwise use the $dir value

    if(is_dir($dir))
    {
        $objects = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
        foreach ($objects as $object)
        {
            if(is_dir($dir."/".$object))
            {
                $this->p_sweep_compile_dir($dir."/".$object); // recurse self and provide deeper dir
            }
            else
            {
                unlink($dir."/".$object);
            }
        }
        unset($object, $objects); // forced memory management
        rmdir($dir);
    }
    else
    {
        die('tried to delete a non-folder from p_sweep_compile_dir');
    }

    unset($dir);
}
```